# Messy code return by using rvest in R

Tags: r, web, rvest

I want to grab web text from taobao.com:

```
shop <- html('http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?spm=a230r.1.14.52.OizVF6&id=42200503654&ns=1&_u=n1b61flaa96&abbucket=7#detail',encoding="utf-8")

shop  %>% 
  html_node(".tb-main-title") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  as.character()
```

But it doesn't work,the result is:

```
  \n     HM7000 钃濈墮鑰虫満 涓枃鎶\xa5 绔嬩綋澹\xb0 涓€鎷栦簩 鍚煶涔\x90\n
```

ps: i try add encoding='utf-8' in html function.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the page encoding of your target page

Response Headers :

```
_Host:detail010236101060.unit.cm4
Age:1862
at_autype:5_100262977
at_cat:item_50005050
at_isb:0
at_itemId:42200503654
at_nick:guoy087
Cache-Control:max-age=3
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Language:zh-CN
Content-Type:text/html;charset=GBK <------ Encoding is GBK
Date:Fri, 27 Mar 2015 08:43:16 GMT
S:STATUS_NORMAL
Server:Tengine
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
Via:wagbridge010238184034.cm4[0,200-0,H]
X-Cache:HIT TCP_MEM_HIT dirn:-2:-2
X-Category:/cat/50008090
```

You can see that the page encoding is not `UTF-8`, it is `GBK` (described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GBK) )

Comment: I have run "shop <- html(url,encoding='gbk')", it seem doesn't work!!

Answer (score 0):

```
html('http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?spm=a230r.1.14.52.OizVF6&id=42200503654&ns=1&_u=n1b61flaa96&abbucket=7#detail') %>% html_node(".tb-main-title") %>% html_text(encoding='utf-8')
```